# How does React-Router works

Tags: javascript, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am using React-Router in my project, and I was amazed that unlike other routing libraries, it won't show 404 error if page is refreshed at any route(say you are at /a/b/c and you refresh the page, it loads /a/b/c instead of showing 404 error). I am not sure how react-router handles it. Maybe that is handled by webpack-dev-server. Please let me know if you know how it works behind the scene.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, this is history API fallback it seems, and I didn't have to do anything like that in react-router.

Comment: it worked! I thought React-Router was doing it. Thanks for the help.